# selection of cells corresponding to a selected row in excel vba

Tags: excel, vba, row, cell

I am writing a macro related to a button "supprimer" (clear) that clear only the data from specific cells ((corresponding row,C),(corresponding row,E)) corresponding to a specific row from a bill (row that matches the reference in the comboBox "Choisir une référence" in the userform), so that the formulas that calculate the total price and search for the item designation not be affected  .

The macro code is as follow:

```
[![Private Sub ajouter_Click()
Dim ligne As Integer: ligne = 2
Dim lignef As Integer: lignef = 6

If (liste_ref.SelText <> "") Then
If (IsNumeric(quantite.Value) = False) Then
MsgBox ("La quantité saisie n'est pas un nombre, veuillez corriger")
Exit Sub
Else
While (ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("articles").Cells(ligne, 3).Value <> "")
If (ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("articles").Cells(ligne, 3).Value = liste_ref.SelText) Then
If (Int(quantite.Value) > Int(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("articles").Cells(ligne, 6).Value)) Then
MsgBox "La quantité en stock pour cette référence n'est que de " & ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("articles").Cells(ligne, 6).Value
Exit Sub
Else
While (ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("facturation").Cells(lignef, 3).Value <> "")
lignef = lignef + 1
Wend
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("facturation").Cells(lignef, 3).Value = liste_ref.SelText
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("facturation").Cells(lignef, 5).Value = quantite.Value
End If
End If

ligne = ligne + 1
Wend
End If
End If
End Sub

Private Sub liste_ref_Change()

End Sub

Private Sub reinitialiser_Click()
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("facturation").Activate
Range("C6:C26").Value = ""
Range("E6:E26").Value = ""
End Sub

Private Sub supprimer_Click()
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("facturation").Activate
Rows(\[C6:C1048576\].Find(liste_ref.Value).Row).Cells(thisrow, 3).Value = ""
Rows(\[C6:C1048576\].Find(liste_ref.Value).Row).Cells(thisrow, 5).Value = ""

End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Activate()

Dim ligne As Integer: ligne = 2

While (ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("articles").Cells(ligne, 3).Value <> "")

liste_ref.AddItem (ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("articles").Cells(ligne, 3).Value)
ligne = ligne + 1

Wend

ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("facturation").Activate

End Sub

Private Sub valider_Click()
Dim reponse As Byte
Dim ligne As Integer: ligne = 2
Dim lignef As Integer: lignef = 6

reponse = MsgBox("Souhaitez-vous valider la facture et mettre à jour les stocks", vbYesNo + vbQuestion)

If (reponse = 6) Then
While (ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("facturation").Cells(lignef, 3).Value <> "")
ligne = 2
While (ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("articles").Cells(ligne, 3).Value <> "")

If (ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("facturation").Cells(lignef, 3) = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("articles").Cells(ligne, 3).Value) Then
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("articles").Cells(ligne, 6).Value = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("articles").Cells(ligne, 6).Value - ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("facturation").Cells(lignef, 5)
End If
ligne = ligne + 1
Wend
lignef = lignef + 1
Wend

msg.Caption = "Les stocks ont été mis jour. La facture peut être éditée."

End If

End Sub][1]][1]
```

The problem is that the code clear the header of the bill!

and how can I make the bill dynamic, so as I cleared a row the other items move up?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is this all your code? What is the value of `thisrow`? [this may be useful](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: project link https://drive.google.com/file/d/1_y0OONAMCQ0n_gPaXYUkP1lUlwBKPQWQ/view?usp=sharing

Comment: FYI, most people here will not download files from unknown sources. Please include sample data and the relevant missing code in your question by [editing it](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/68322194/edit)